# How to get product name/version in C/C++ for macOS (ie get "Mac OS" and "10.12.5")

Tags: c, macos, operating-system, version

I need to get the information in the title. I made sysctl calls to the following variables and it gave me other (not useful) information (usually regarding the kernel not the OS): KERN_VERSION, KERN_OSVERSION, KERN_TYPE, KERN_RELEASE.

I looked at the source code for the command `sw_vers` here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/DarwinTools/DarwinTools-1/sw_vers.c and tried to implement what they did however while I was able to include  my computer was unable to find  and thus I coulnd't implement. When I look through my /include/ directory I can't find /CoreFoundation/ at all so I don't know where I'm pulling it from.

Any ideas on how I can get this using C/C++?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't made much research, have you?  It took me 1 google search at 30 seconds to find out KERN_VERSION is defined in sys/sysctl.h.  Maybe using `sysctl_rdstring` defined in this same header will get you somewhere.

Comment: Note that 10.12.5 is a version of macOS Sierra — different capitalization on the macOS part.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: I think you've missed the point — the OP knows about those, but they do not provide the answer that is wanted.

Comment: The open source repository you cited has this directory: https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/, which seems to contain the CoreFoundation sources. Is executing `sw_vers` and parsing its output not an option?

Comment: @jxh Ugh unfortunately that repo only carries the missing header file but not it's source (and that header includes other missing files). And no I specifically cannot use the command line

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot invoke `sw_vers`? Are you implementing a  kernel driver? Can you explain what you plan to do with this information?

Comment: Note that calling `sw_vers` via `popen` or `fork`/`exec` is not the same as using the command line.

Comment: @jxh My project currently has been implemented using command line/parsing but in the V2 of our product we are building it from kernel calls using C/C++ to increase speed

Comment: How often are you getting the version information?  How long does it take to run `sw_vers`?  Are you sure that the speed benefit is outweighed by the difficulty of finding out how to do it?  (FWIW, I note that `sw_vers` on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 reports `ProductName: Mac OS X` — `ProductVersion: 10.12.5` — `BuildVersion: 16F73` so the code hasn't caught up with the marketing yet.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler hmm that's interesting it isn't saying macOS. That is one thing I am hoping to be able to differentiate anyways so that almost takes away the validity of parsing sw_vers. And I may be having a chat with my boss to see if we can't use the command line for this one as it seems after a couple hours scouring the internet that it is seemingly impossible

Comment: It can be done — the program `sw_vers` demonstrates that it can be done.  What's less clear is what the `sw_vers` program is doing; what it is interrogating to find the information.  And if you find it involves using some Objective-C code, would that be acceptable?  I note that `man sw_vers` shows you can invoke it with an option to get any one of the fields without the tag prefix (`sw_vers -productName` — single-dash).  It also mentions files `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` and 
`/System/Library/CoreServices/ServerVersion.plist` — does that help?

Answer (score 5):

If this were my project, I would simply invoke the `sw_vers` utility and parse its output. You can use `popen` to accomplish this, illustrated below:

```
char buf[1024];
unsigned buflen = 0;
char line[256];
FILE *sw_vers = popen("sw_vers", "r");
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), sw_vers) != NULL) {
    int l = snprintf(buf + buflen, sizeof(buf) - buflen, "%s", line);
    buflen += l;
    assert(buflen < sizeof(buf));
}
pclose(sw_vers);
```

Parse the output to get the relevant information. On my system, the output is:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.5
BuildVersion:   16F73
```

So, you could parse each line instead of storing it all into a buffer as illustrated.

Once the information is stored in your program, the result can be cached. Any future queries by your same program can use the cached result rather than invoking `sw_vers` again.

Comment: You can also add parameters to make the result specific. For example:  
sw_vers -productVersion (to give you OS version number like 10.11.1)  
sw_vers -buildVersion (to give you something like 15E01)  
sw_vers -productName (to give you something like "Mac OS X")

Comment: what if the system locale is something other than english? parsing will fail?

Comment: @VikasPushkar: You could use the command line to specify the information of interest, as [Neilvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683285/how-to-get-product-name-version-in-c-c-for-macos-ie-get-mac-os-and-10-12-5/44684199?noredirect=1#comment100160326_44684199) suggests, or you could parse by line instead (since each line represents the info in a particular order).